# Excel Regression with Multiple Data Sets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset of job titles, salaries, and experience levels. I want to regress salary on experience BY job title. (I.E. several different regression analyses, one for each job title). Any way to do this without separating or sorting the data? I think an array formula plus INTERCEPT and SLOPE might do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. For single-term models, `SLOPE`, `INTERCEPT`, and `RSQ` as array formulas will do it:

```
=SLOPE(IF(Table1[Job Title]=E2,Table1[Salary]),IF(Table1[Job Title]=E2,Table1[Experience]))
```

Just change `SLOPE` to `INTERCEPT` or `RSQ` to get those values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the data analysis toolpak, built-in regression tool.